# How to configure cscope to invoke vim to open file

Tags: vim, cscope

I always `cscope` to find a symbol such `bcm_vlan_stat_t`. I always run `cscope -Rq` to find a C symbol and when I select a entry in result, cscope invoke vi (not vim) to open file. So what can I do to let cscope invoke vim?

Comment: What you think is "vi" is almost certainly "vim".

Comment: @romainl but some vim plugins can`t run in vi,so I want to change behavor of cscope.

Comment: a) Vi doesn't have plugins at all and b) you almost certainly don't have vi on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

Set your cscope editor to `vim` so that it open files using vim,

```
export CSCOPE_EDITOR=vim
```

You may like to save in your rc file, for instance `~/.bashrc` if you are using bash.

Comment: I very much doubt `cscope` understand bash `alias`.